# Where to store non key-value parameters in Azure Service Fabric application

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I want to add custom settings to my application, like this:

```
 <Parameter Name="AuthService1" url="http://localhost:11200/" method="post" value3="123" />
 <Parameter Name="AuthService2" url="https://auth.com/" method="get" value3="133" />
```

Or grouped key-value parameters like this:

```
<subSettings name="AuthService1">
    <parametr name="url" value ="http://localhost:11200/" />
    <parametr name="method" value ="post" />
<subSettings/>
<subSettings name="AuthService2">
    <parametr name="url" value ="https://auth.com/" />
    <parametr name="method" value ="get" />
<subSettings/>
```

Where i can store it?

Answer (score 0):

Some options I can think of:

1. Use json (or xml) as a value, like this:

   ```
   <Parameter Name="AuthService1" Value="{&quot;Url&quot;:&quot;http://localhost:11200/&quot;,&quot;Method&quot;:&quot;post&quot;,&quot;value3&quot;:123}">
   ```
2. Use multiple parameters like this:

   ```
   <Parameter Name="AuthService1.Url" Value="http://localhost:11200/" /> 
   <Parameter Name="AuthService1.Method" Value="Post" /> 
   <Parameter Name="AuthService1.Value3" Value="123" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to solve this problem, I'd rather go with the grouped approach. You can have sections in Service Fabric "Settings.xml" as below:

```
<Section Name="AuthService1">
    <Parameter Name="Url" Value="http://localhost:11200/" />
    <Parameter Name="Method" Value="POST" />
</Section>
```

Now, if you were to access these settings in your code, you'll do something like:

```
Configuration.GetSection("AuthService1")["Url"];
```

OR

```
Configuration["AuthService1:Url"];
```

In the given examples above, I'm assuming that Configuration is the Microsoft.Extensions.IConfiguration object.

Comment: @DiegoTM if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as an answer or otherwise let me know how I can help :-)